# What is causing this error in my program: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"

Tags: ada

In the program below I wanted to create a nameBook which is an array of string so that I can store 5 names. You can see how I did this below. When I try to compile I get the errors shown below. What is the issue here?

```
with ada.integer_text_io; use ada.integer_text_io;
with ada.text_io; use ada.text_io;
with ada.strings.unbounded; use ada.strings.unbounded;

procedure nameStorer is

nameBook : array(1..5) of unbounded_string; 

begin
nameBook := ("tom","mary","harry","william","kate");

end nameStorer;
```

Compile errors:

```
nameStorer.adb:10:16: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"
nameStorer.adb:10:16: found a string type
nameStorer.adb:10:24: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"
nameStorer.adb:10:24: found a string type
nameStorer.adb:10:33: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"
nameStorer.adb:10:33: found a string type
nameStorer.adb:10:40: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"
nameStorer.adb:10:40: found a string type
nameStorer.adb:10:47: expected private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"
nameStorer.adb:10:47: found a string type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"tom","mary","harry","william","kate"` are literals of type `String` (`Standard.String`, to be exact). Your `nameBook` is an array of type `Unbounded_String` (`Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String`). You need to convert the string literals to Unbounded_Strings.

Take a look at `To_Unbounded_String` in [`Ada.Strings.Unbounded` (RM A.4.5/9)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html)

Comment: What do I need to convert? "tom", "mary" etx? Why do i need to convert them, is there not a way just to declare them as unbounded strings from the begining?

Comment: Ada does not have unbounded string literals, so yes, you need to convert each string

Comment: I currently am doing it in this way, dictionary := (To_Unbounded_String("chris"),To_Unbounded_String("martin"),To_Unbounded_String("jacky"),To_Unbounded_String("police"));, Is there a better way?

Comment: Well you could abuse the rename method, and rename the To_Unbounded_String() function to something else like '+', To_UStr, etc.

Comment: That's the correct way. Some people like to rename to_unbounded_string to the unary plus sign, like this: function "+"(S : in String) return Unbounded_String renames Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String; and then do +"foo"